# Question about the gap between the airstairs and the aircraft

Tags: safety

Is there universal code/height between the ramp at the top of the airstairs and the aircraft. If not, what is the expected gap between the aircraft and the airstairs when embarking or disembarking?

Comment: Are you asking about the horizontal gap or about the height difference?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, there is a gap between the air stairs ramp and the aircraft. It can be due to some reasons like

1. Preventing damage to the fuselage
2. The ramp not fitting all the
   aircraft as their fuselage dimensions are different.

According to [FAA Advisory Circular 150/5220-21C,](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_150_5220-21C.pdf)

> No gap between vehicle and ramp will exceed 5/8 in (16 mm).

Related question: [What is the maximum acceptable gap between the jet bridge and airplane door?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/19530/66887)